# angularjs karma unable to find function inside scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have an AngularJS function

```
$scope.goneHome = () => {
  filterSegmentStateService.resetPersistence();
};
```

That I'm trying to unit test.

```
/* eslint-disable */

/**
 * Test for campaign tags.
 */
describe('Header component', () => {
  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('keywordsApp');
  });

  var $componentController, scope, component, element, filterSegmentStateService;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, _$componentController_, _filterSegmentStateService_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    filterSegmentStateService = _filterSegmentStateService_;
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
    component = $componentController('headerComponent', { $scope: scope });
  }));

  it('should run filterSegmentStateService function if goneHome function is selected', function () {
    console.log('TESTING 123');
    console.log(filterSegmentStateService);
    console.log(scope);
    console.log(scope.goneHome());
    expect(filterSegmentStateService.resetPersistence).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

So `filterSegmentStateService` shows up in my log as well as `scope` but `scope.goneHome()` returns `undefined`

So I've looked at `scope` and it has logged the following:

```
Scope {
    $$childTail: null,
    $$childHead: null,
    $$nextSibling: null,
    $$watchers: null,
    $$listeners: Object {},
    $$listenerCount: Object {},
    $$watchersCount: 0,
    $id: 120,
    $$ChildScope: null,
    $parent: Scope {
        $id: 119,
        $$childTail: Scope {
            $$childTail: ...,
            $$childHead: ...,
            $$nextSibling: ...,
            $$watchers: ...,
            $$listeners: ...,
            $$listenerCount: ...,
            $$watchersCount: ...,
            $id: ...,
            $$ChildScope: ...,
            $parent: ...,
            $$prevSibling: ...,
            goneHome: ...,
            $ctrl: ...
        },
        $$childHead: Scope {
            $$childTail: ...,
            $$childHead: ...,
            $$nextSibling: ...,
            $$watchers: ...,
            $$listeners: ...,
            $$listenerCount: ...,
            $$watchersCount: ...,
            $id: ...,
            $$ChildScope: ...,
            $parent: ...,
            $$prevSibling: ...,
            goneHome: ...,
            $ctrl: ...
        },
        $$prevSibling: null,
        $$nextSibling: null,
        $$watchers: [..., ...],
        $parent: null,
        $$phase: null,
        $root: Scope {
            $id: ...,
            $$childTail: ...,
            $$childHead: ...,
            $$prevSibling: ...,
            $$nextSibling: ...,
            $$watchers: ...,
            $parent: ...,
            $$phase: ...,
            $root: ...,
            $$destroyed: ...,
            $$listeners: ...,
            $$listenerCount: ...,
            $$watchersCount: ...,
            $$isolateBindings: ...,
            $$asyncQueue: ...,
            $$postDigestQueue: ...,
            $$applyAsyncQueue: ...,
            gsGlobalVariables: ...,
            $$ChildScope: ...
        },
        $$destroyed: false,
        $$listeners: Object {
            $locationChangeSuccess: ...,
            $destroy: ...
        },
        $$listenerCount: Object {
            $locationChangeSuccess: ...,
            $destroy: ...
        },
        $$watchersCount: 2,
        $$isolateBindings: null,
        $$asyncQueue: [..., ..., ..., ...],
        $$postDigestQueue: [],
        $$applyAsyncQueue: [],
        gsGlobalVariables: Object {
            pageLoaded: ...,
            requestError: ...,
            windowStatusLoadMessage: ...
        },
        $$ChildScope: function ChildScope() { ...
        }
    },
    $$prevSibling: null,
    goneHome: function() { ...
    },
    $ctrl: HeaderController {
        $rootScope: Scope {
            $id: ...,
            $$childTail: ...,
            $$childHead: ...,
            $$prevSibling: ...,
            $$nextSibling: ...,
            $$watchers: ...,
            $parent: ...,
            $$phase: ...,
            $root: ...,
            $$destroyed: ...,
            $$listeners: ...,
            $$listenerCount: ...,
            $$watchersCount: ...,
            $$isolateBindings: ...,
            $$asyncQueue: ...,
            $$postDigestQueue: ...,
            $$applyAsyncQueue: ...,
            gsGlobalVariables: ...,
            $$ChildScope: ...
        },
        $scope: Scope {
            $$childTail: ...,
            $$childHead: ...,
            $$nextSibling: ...,
            $$watchers: ...,
            $$listeners: ...,
            $$listenerCount: ...,
            $$watchersCount: ...,
            $id: ...,
            $$ChildScope: ...,
            $parent: ...,
            $$prevSibling: ...,
            goneHome: ...,
            $ctrl: ...
        },
        filterSegmentStateService: filterSegmentStateService {
            pagination: ...,
            sort: ...,
            getFilterAll: ...,
            setCurrentPage: ...,
            getCurrentPage: ...,
            getPaginationState: ...,
            getSort: ...,
            groupView: ...,
            setLanguageFilter: ...,
            getLanguageFilter: ...,
            resetLanguageFilter: ...,
            getStatusFilter: ...,
            getThrottleFilter: ...,
            resetStatusFilter: ...,
            setFilterValues: ...,
            setTypesFilter: ...,
            getFilterOptionByLabel: ...,
            resetTypesFilter: ...,
            getTypesFilter: ...,
            setGroupsFilter: ...,
            getGroupsFilter: ...,
            toggleView: ...,
            getView: ...,
            isGroupView: ...,
            unselectGroups: ...,
            setDefaultListView: ...,
            selectGroup: ...,
            isGroupSelected: ...,
            groupSelected: ...,
            getSelectedGroup: ...,
            resetPersistence: ...
        }
    }
}
```

So inside that I do actually see the following.

```
goneHome: function() { ...
},
```

Why am I unable to use this function to run `filterSegmentStateService.resetPersistence()` in my controller function?

Comment: In what environment your test is running? PhantomJS? Are you sure it supports arrow functions? Does it work if you don't use arrow function but 'traditional' function declaration? Maybe you must transpile your code before running your tests.

Comment: The same result whether I use arrow fucntions or not.

Comment: You say `scope.goneHome()` returns `undefined`, but this feels quite normal since there is no `return` statement in the function. If you want auto return, i think you must removes the braces.